# How can I make an ad specific to desktop, and another to mobile?

Tags: css, adsense

I know this may seem like a very simple question, but please understand I know very little about CSS.
Essentially, I have a responsive website with two columns. I want to add an ad on the right for Desktop, and one of the left for Mobile. So far so good, I only have to copy and adapt the code they provide on their website, and this did work for mobile, hiding the ad:

```
<style type="text/css">
.adslot_1 { display:inline-block; width: 320px; height: 50px; }
@media (max-width: 400px) { .adslot_1 { display: none; } }
</style>
<ins class="adsbygoogle adslot_1"
   data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234"
   data-ad-slot="5678"></ins>
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>
```

However, how can I adapt this for desktop? I assumed all I had was to change the *max-width: 400px* to *min-width*, but it doesn't seem to be working at all... any ideas on why, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many cases scripts that insert content dynamically tend to modify the element's inline CSS properties and that usually overrides the style definitions, because of specificity. You can learn more on specificity in CSS [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

What I would recommend you to do is to add `!important` to your style definition to see if that does hide the element. Your style should look something like: (I added some extra info to the `@media` query.

```css
.adslot_1 {
    display:inline-block; 
    width: 320px;
    height: 50px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .adslot_1 {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

What you could also do is open your browser's inspect tools (developer tools) and inspect that specific element to see which styles are being applied and also check that based on media query.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that really sounded like chinese to me, since I'm not very knowledgeable about CSS. So, basically, I can add !important , and that should essentially force the rule to be applied?

Comment: In very broad terms for your case yes, it prioritizes the style to be applied, basically indicating that it's important this specific rule is applied.

Comment: Thanks! It seems the solution was something way, way sillier - I forgot to change .adslot1 to .adslot2 in the coding, and so either both ads appeared at the same time, or they didn't. D'OH! Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem if the answer worked for you, you can accept it :)